# $f(0)=f(1)$ but no point with $f'(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

\begin{equation}
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x, \quad 0\leqslant x < 1,\\
    0, \quad x=1.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

This function is differentiable at $(0,1)$ but its derivative is never zero on $(0,1)$. How can this be? Doesn't Rolle's theorem say the derivative has to be zero somewhere in $(0,1)$? Please provide a reason with your answer.

Comment: What conditions must be satisfied for Rolle's theorem to hold?  Which of these conditions is not satisfied by your problem?

Answer (score 7):

Rolle's theorem says:

If a real-valued function $f$ is **continuous** on a proper closed interval $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and $f(a) = f(b)$, then there exists at least one $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Here Rolle's theorem cannot be applied since $f(x)$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

For Rolle's theorem to be applicable, a function must be continuous on a closed interval, but this particular function is clearly discontinuous at $x = 1$.

Here's the statement of the Rolle's Theorem:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers such that $a < b$. Suppose that $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that
>
> (i) $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$;
>
> (ii) the derivative $f^\prime(x)$ exists for all $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$; and
>
> (iii) $f(a) = f(b)$.
>
> Then there is some real number $c$ such that $a < c< b$ and $f^\prime (c) = 0$.